# Authentication using Cognito and Okta OIDC without Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, okta

I'm pretty sure I've answered this question myself but I just want to confirm that this is impossible.
So I'm using AWS Cognito with added Okta OIDC, now in my app I'm using `amazon-cognito-identity-js`. Initially I thought that I will be able to authenticate user without using hosted UI, but it gives me `UserNotFoundException` when I'm using users from external provider (logging via hosted UI -> selecting provider (okta) works as expected).

Is there any work around for this knowing that I'll be using only this one external provider?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Hosted UI is the only option for federated providers. You can however have users skip the UI by passing your identity provider in the [Authorize URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html#get-authorize-request-parameters)

Comment: Right, same if you select only the federated provider option in a hosted UI configuration. Anyway, I was hoping to just pass the username and password to some magical endpoint and not have my user redirected. That answers my question though, thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, that is commonly referred to as Delegated Authentication (vs Federated Auth) usually enabled by something like LDAP. If it's a requirement you might be able to piece something together with custom auth but I'd really just avoid cognito for anything beyond trivial use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can have federated providers without using the hosted UI by using this function in Amplify: `Auth.federatedSignIn`